# Top down Dynamic programming VS recursive naive solution. Checking run time execution

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I've written a program that finds the total number of increasing subsequence with K length.

The program is implemented in 2 ways.

1. Naive recursive way increase_subseq_k()
2. Top down DP way increase_subseq_k_top_down()

Code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int helper(vector<int> v, int k, int idx){
    if(k==0) return 0;
    if(k==1) return 1;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=idx+1; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i]>v[idx]){
            count+=helper(v,k-1,i);
        }
    }
    return count;
}

int increase_subseq_k(vector<int> v, int k){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        count+=helper(v,k,i);
    }
    return count;

}

int helper_top_down(vector<int> v, int k, int idx, vector<vector<int>>& dp){
    if(k==0){
        dp[k][idx]=0;
        return 0;
    }
    if(k==1){
        dp[k][idx]=1;
        return 1;
    }
    if(dp[k][idx]!=-1) return dp[k][idx];
    int count=0;
    for(int i=idx+1; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        if(v[i]>v[idx]){
            count+=helper_top_down(v,k-1,i, dp);
        }
    }
    dp[k][idx]=count;
    return count;
}

int increase_subseq_k_top_down(vector<int> v, int k){
    vector<vector<int>> dp(k+1, vector<int>(v.size(), -1));
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++)
    {
        count+=helper_top_down(v,k,i, dp);
    }
    return count;

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v = {12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14, 16, 20};
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<increase_subseq_k(v, 4)<<endl;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    cout<<duration<<endl;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    cout<<increase_subseq_k_top_down(v, 4)<<endl;
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration2 = duration_cast<microseconds>( t4 - t3 ).count();
    cout<<duration2<<endl;
}
```

my question is: I am trying to compute the execution time of the 2 different methods, but I am getting very similar numbers, which means the top down DP approach isn't actually improving the run time of the algorithm at all.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: 1. It's not going to take very many microseconds to solve such a small instance of the problem.  You should use a much bigger one so you can measure a significant time.  2. The naive version may be slower in the worst case, but that doesn't mean it will be slower on every instance of the problem.  3.  you shouldn't include the time to print out the answer in your measurements, since it can be relatively large and variable.

Comment: I get times of 46ms vs 13ms (2018 Macbook Pro, i7 3.1GHz). However, that is useless, since you are measuring the time of `std::cout << ... << std::endl;`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't mention what times you get. I tested it on my 2018 MacBook Pro, i7 3.1 GHz, and I get times of around 46ms for recursive implementation vs 13 ms for the dynamic-programming implementation. But I will explain below why these values should be discarded.
2. As, @Matt Timmermans pointed out in the comment, measuring a small function with small inputs like this once does not give reliable times. Instead, I suggest that you use a micro-benchmarking framework. Here is my implementation with "google-benchmark".
3. You are measuring `std::cout << ... << std::endl;`. `std::endl` includes `std::flush` which is very slow.

### Complexity

Your two solutions are O(N^2) and O(N^3) where N is equal to `v.size()` in your code. It is also dependent on K, where K is the second argument to the function. (The numbers for that are not convincing, maybe log K, and K log K, but only for N fixed at 30).

Code for the complexity calculation can be found at the very end. Here's the result table. Look for the lines `BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>_BigO                  289.38 N^3     288.28 N^3` and `BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>_BigO           6.20 N^2       6.20 N^2`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                                Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/5/5/42                    40 ns         40 ns   13791473
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/10/5/42                  267 ns        266 ns    2481574
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/20/5/42                 2621 ns       2613 ns     257017
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/40/5/42                61676 ns      61502 ns      11720
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/80/5/42              1424755 ns    1420357 ns        502
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/160/5/42            49581330 ns   49290286 ns         14
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/320/5/42          2023321331 ns 2022037000 ns          1
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>/640/5/42          76810469575 ns 76516177000 ns          1
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>_BigO                  289.38 N^3     288.28 N^3 
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k>_RMS                       27 %         27 % 
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/5/5/42          839 ns        839 ns     756855
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/10/5/42        1043 ns       1042 ns     663193
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/20/5/42        1795 ns       1794 ns     386905
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/40/5/42        5996 ns       5995 ns     119031
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/80/5/42       31001 ns      30993 ns      22078
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/160/5/42     150695 ns     150350 ns       4748
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/320/5/42     631402 ns     630742 ns       1155
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>/640/5/42    2541040 ns    2540148 ns        277
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>_BigO           6.20 N^2       6.20 N^2 
BM_Generic<increase_subseq_k_top_down>_RMS               1 %          1 %
```

### Notes on my solution below

- Benchmark is for fixed input. You probably care about the performance as the input size is increased. I did not implement this yet. Here is the documentation how to do this: https://github.com/google/benchmark . *See update below*!
- The code with `std::cout` prints to the command line, you need to filter this with `grep BM` or similar, to only get the output you want.

### Results from Benchmarking

```
2018-07-03 20:50:35
Running ./benchmark_main
Run on (8 X 3100 MHz CPU s)
CPU Caches:
  L1 Data 32K (x4)
  L1 Instruction 32K (x4)
  L2 Unified 262K (x4)
  L3 Unified 8388K (x1)
------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                     Time           CPU Iterations
------------------------------------------------------------
BM_Subseq                 15086 ns      15079 ns      40718
BM_SubseqTopDown           9198 ns       9196 ns      70722
BM_SubseqNoIO             11782 ns      11774 ns      55523
BM_SubseqTopDownNoIO       6391 ns       6384 ns     108056
```

### Code for Benchmarking

```
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>


#include "subsequence.h"

static void BM_Subseq(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::vector<int> v = {12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14, 16, 20};
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::cout << increase_subseq_k(v, 4) << std::endl;
    }
}

static void BM_SubseqNoIO(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::vector<int> v = {12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14, 16, 20};
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(increase_subseq_k(v, 4));
    }
}


static void BM_SubseqTopDown(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::vector<int> v = {12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14, 16, 20};
    for (auto _ : state) {
        std::cout << increase_subseq_k_top_down(v, 4) << std::endl;
    }
}

static void BM_SubseqTopDownNoIO(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::vector<int> v = {12, 8, 11, 13, 10, 15, 14, 16, 20};
    for (auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(increase_subseq_k_top_down(v, 4));
    }
}

BENCHMARK(BM_Subseq);
BENCHMARK(BM_SubseqTopDown);
BENCHMARK(BM_SubseqNoIO);
BENCHMARK(BM_SubseqTopDownNoIO);

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

### UPDATE: Complexity Code

Here's the code to compute complexity.

```
   #include <random>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include "subsequence.h"

std::vector<int> GetRandomVector(std::size_t size, int seed) {
    std::vector<int> result;
    result.reserve(size);

    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
    // TODO: What should be the right distribution?
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 100);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result.push_back(dis(gen));
    }
    return result;
}

/** Wrapper code to benchmark a function F (which is compiled into the code as a
 * template argument). We use it here to evaluate on "increase_subseq_k" and
 * "increase_subseq_k_top_down".
 *
 * @tparam F Function to benchmark
 */
template<int (*F)(const std::vector<int> &, int)>
static void BM_Generic(benchmark::State &state) {
    std::vector<int> v = GetRandomVector(state.range(0), state.range(2));
    for (auto _ : state) {
        benchmark::DoNotOptimize(F(v, state.range(1)));
    }
    state.SetComplexityN(state.range(0));
}


/** Generates custom arguments of triples (n, k, seed). Seed is used for the
 * random vector generator and hardcoded to 42.
 *
 * Play around with this function. I've left the clearest example as default
 * (showing very little variation from  the O(N^2) and O(N^3) of the two
 * implementations. But also interesting is to generate different values for 'k'
 * while varying n. However, google-benchmark only does complexity analysis on
 * one variable, so the analysis would have to be done in a different tool.
 *
 * Just iterating over k gives log K and K log K complexity, but only when I
 * kept n=30.
 */
static void CustomArguments(benchmark::internal::Benchmark *b) {
    constexpr int seed = 42;
    const int i = 5;
//        const int n = 30;
    for (int n = std::max(1, i); n < 1000; n *= 2)
//                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        b->Args({n, i, seed});
}

BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Generic, increase_subseq_k)->Apply(
        CustomArguments)->Complexity();
BENCHMARK_TEMPLATE(BM_Generic, increase_subseq_k_top_down)->Apply(
        CustomArguments)->Complexity();

BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```